# Show language information with bibliography style "apalike"?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, languages

Right now I use the `natbib` package and the `apalike` bibliography style. I have multiple references in Dutch and Chinese and I'd like to show this information in the full reference in the reference list at the end.

However, it seems that `apalike` doesn't use this information. Any suggestions for similar bib styles that are able to do this?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I'd like to show *this information) in the full reference" [emphasis added]. Do you want to provide a note which says (in effect) "This piece was published in Dutch/Chinese/whatever"?

Comment: `biblatex` has a `language` field and prints the field if their value is not equal to the current document language. But of course that would involve switching from `natbib` to `biblatex` and you would have to find a new style (`apalike.bst` can not be used with `biblatex` - like all `.bst` files), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864